# Why would you set the JavaScript prototype to an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

In this [article](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS2.html)

The prototype object is being set to the "superclass"

```
function Mammal(name){ 
    this.name=name;
    this.offspring=[];
} 

Cat.prototype = new Mammal();
```

In the code that I am reading right now, it has this construct

```
COMPANY.BILLING = function(){
    //more code
}

COMPANY.BILLING.prototype = (function(COMPANY){
    //more code
})(COMPANY)
```

I am confused, why would you set the value of the prototype object to an anonymous function?  This is not some sort of inheritance, right?

Is this some sort of a JavaScript pattern?

Comment: Look for information on IIFE.

Comment: Oh okay, so you mean you just wanted to call the function immediately? The setting of the prototype object doesn't matter?  Thanks

Comment: Didn't you basically ask this same question yesterday?

Comment: Sorry if it may seem connected, I am on the Javascript Inheritance reading now and I am just confused because I was thinking that you would use the prototype object to mimic inheritance.  And based on my initial reading, these are the thoughts that came to my mind.  The code that I am debugging has this construct and it does not have any idea of inheritance so that's why I asked.  I asked myself, why the heck would you set the prototype object to an anonymous functions if you are going to implement inheritance?  Sorry, I know my question is vague to you. I just want to grasp the concept. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Careful, the prototype is not set to an anonymous function there, but to it's return value:

```
COMPANY.BILLING.prototype = (function(COMPANY){
    //more code
})(COMPANY);
  ^^^^^^^^^  -> the function is called immediately
```

This means that the prototype is assigned the self-calling function's return value, whatever that might be:

```
COMPANY.BILLING.prototype = (function(COMPANY){
    return new Foo();  // the new Foo will be assigned to the prototype
})(COMPANY);
```

Usually, these self-calling functions are wrapped around chunks of code to avoid polluting a scope with symbol names, preventing duplicate symbol names and, last but not least, preventing confusion about the purpose of a variable (JavaScript only has functional scoping, at least current versions do). Any variable/function name declared in a function body is visible in the containing function body, but not outside:

```
var sampleVariable; // this is visible across this example

COMPANY.BILLING.prototype = (function(COMPANY){
    var yetAnotherVariable;  // this is only visible "inside" the self-calling function

    return new Foo();  // the new Foo will be assigned to the prototype
})(COMPANY);
```